# Changing UIScrollView frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I'm trying to set a scrollview's position by setting its frame:

```
[_scrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 267, 842)];
```

but after doing this the actual position gets set to

```
_scrollView - x:66.000000 y:-248.000000 w:267.000000 h:842.000000
```

if i set it to

```
[_scrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 267, 842)];
```

the frame gets set to

```
_scrollView - x:0.000000 y:-2.000000 w:267.000000 h:842.000000
```

i'm using storyboards and the UIView has a couple of other elements but none of them have autosizing and i'm not using autolayout.

Comment: put you whole code  of creation of scrollview

Comment: What do you mean by "the actual position"? In other words, where are you getting this (66, -248) value from?